# How to supply a data logger with electricity inside a tumble dryer at 80 °C?

Tags: power-supply, batteries, datalogger

I have constructed a data logger which will be used in a tumble dryer. During the drying process the temperatures inside are 60-80 °C. The data logger is designed to move freely inside the tumbler. The data logger is very compact. How would you supply it with electricity (3 V, 50 mA)?

Comment: How much power/ energy does the data logger require?

Comment: Voltage 3 V and current ~50 mA

Comment: 50 mA is massive for a data logger though, especially for a tiny 3V device. What kind of sensors do you use that requires it?

Comment: That's true. It's going to be a wireless logger which doesn't utilize online data transfer via radio, but sound. Like in a submarine. The current consumption is variable.

Comment: So (@EsatBecco) 50mA peak, then? What duty cycle, how much is the quiescent current, and how long do you want it to run for?

Comment: I am not sure. The speaker is connected to an amplifier and that is connected to a microcontroller. The standby current should be some mA and operating current around 30-50 mA. I want it to run for at least 1h / experiment. And then as many cycles as possible

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are some specialty lithium batteries (LiSOCl2) that can take up to 125°C.
For an example see [Tadirn TLH batteries](https://tadiranbat.com/applications/high-temperature/).
Yet [another manufacturer](https://www.huajubattery.com/high-temperature-battery/) using a similar Li chemistry claims a 165°C limit.